# registrar un dato fecha con dapper

Tags: mysql, c#, dapper

Trabajo con Net6, Dapper, MySql al persistir un registro hago lo siguiente

```
public async Task CreateAsync(Cliente entity)
        {
            entity.FechaAlta = DateTime.Now;
            var sql = "INSERT INTO clientes(nombre, direccion, fecha_alta, estado) VALUES(@nombre, @direccion, @fecha_alta, @estado)";
            using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DefaultConnection")))
            {
                connection.Open();
                await connection.ExecuteAsync(sql, new
                {
                    entity.Nombre,
                    entity.Direccion,
                    fecha_alta = entity.FechaAlta,
                    entity.Estado
                });
            }
        }
```

Porque la `FechaAlta` lo seteo con `datetime` tengo que hacer el new..... hay manera de evitar eso?

Esperaba que quede así  `await connection.ExecuteAsync(sql, entity);`

Comment: Y porque no cambias el nombre de la propiedad ???

Comment: Cambiar el nombre de la propiedad no creo que lo solucione....